# Shorten bolt with a sleeve of some sort?

Tags: bolts, hardware, fastener

I have a reverse osmosis kit, and the faucet has a really long bolt which you use to attach it to your countertop. I can't get a tool up there to tighten it because the sink basin is in the way. I wonder if there is something like a sleeve I can put over the bolt so that the tightening nut sits much lower. Then I can get at it more easily with a tool. Does this thing have a name?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a "bushing", "sleeve bushing", or "sleeve bearing". They're commonly available at hardware stores in brass, bronze, aluminum, plastic (nylon), and steel, and they can be stacked or cut to achieve a custom length.

Comment: Could be as simple as a length of pvc or abs pipe. But you also might consider getting a 'basin wrench'. They're cheap and very handy.

Answer (score 3):

A sink (or basin) wrench is your friend

[image: Basin wrench]

The head turns through 90 degrees, and is spring-loaded to fit on the nut you're trying to tighten (or loosen). An invaluable tool for plumbing of all sorts, and very cheap.